# Cypher COLLECT clause to build a list where some lists could be empty

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database in which I have Entity nodes, User nodes, and a couple of relationships including LIKES, POSTED_BY.  I'm trying to write a query to achieve this objective:

Find all Entity nodes that a particular user LIKES or those that have been POSTED_BY that User

Note that I have simplified my query - in real I have a bunch of other conditions similar to the above.

I'm trying to use a COLLECT clause to aggregate the list of all Entity nodes, and build on that line by line.

```
MATCH (e)<-[:LIKES]-(me:User{id: 'rJVbpcqzf'} )
WITH me, COLLECT(e) AS all_entities
MATCH (e)-[:POSTED_BY]->(me)
WITH me, all_entities + COLLECT(e) AS all_entities
UNWIND all_entities AS e
WITH DISTINCT e
RETURN e;
```

This seems to be returning the correct list ONLY if there is at least one Entity that the user has liked (i.e., if the first COLLECT returns a non-empty list).  However, if there is no Entity that I have liked, the entire query returns empty.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`OPTIONAL MATCH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/optional-match/):

```
MATCH (me:User {id: 'rJVbpcqzf'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (me)-[:LIKES|POSTED_BY]->(e)
RETURN collect(DISTINCT e) AS all_entities
```

Notes:

1. Instead of collecting and unwinding, you can simply use `DISTINCT`. You can also use [`DISTINCT` with `collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating).
2. You can also use [multiple relationship types](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#match-on-multiple-rel-types), i.e. the `LIKES|POSTED_BY` for the relationship type here.